# How to calculate infinite series on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, series, symbolic-math

I'm having trouble calculating a series on MATLAB. I'm trying to use the symbolic toolbox, but MATLAB keeps busy and never returns my result. This is my code:

```
function Y = ProbCollision_S (n,tp,s,T)

   syms k;

   format long;

   Y = double(symsum(exp(-n.*s./T).*((n.*s./T).^k).*(1-(1-k.*tp./s).^k)./factorial(k),2,Inf));

end
```

Please help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the ending sum parameter (`Inf`) to something finite? Like 4, or 6?  What happens when you change this parameter?  Does the sum converge then?

Comment: The series might be divergent, then matlab will fail converting to double. What parameters do you use?

Comment: You should try to look over the equation. If you only test `symsum` I think that you should use a simpler equation to find out if infinite sums work. The problem with your function is that it may only converge for some values on `n,tp,s,T`. assume that all values are set to 1. This means that you have the equation `exp(-1) * ( 1-(1-k)^k )/factorial(k)`, which can be approximated with `exp(-1) * (1-k)^k/factorial(k)`. Sure it is alternating, but I doubt that the function converges.

Comment: Please include values for n, tp, s, T for which you see problems.